# summing the values of a column using awk programming

Tags: awk

I have a file having arrangement like as given below:

```
* * *
1.00000000   5.00000000   6.00000000    2.147428385340250122e-04
2.00000000   5.00000000   9.00000000    4.147428385340250122e-03
3.00000000   5.00000000   1.00000000    8.147428385340250122e-04
* * *
1.00000000   6.00000000   2.00000000    1.147428385340250122e-06
2.00000000   8.00000000   3.00000000    9.147428385340250122e-05
3.00000000   9.00000000   1.00000000    3.147428385340250122e-04
4.00000000   4.00000000   5.00000000    8.147428385340250122e-04
* * *
```

I just want to sum the values of last column row wise as depicted below:

```
1.00000000   2.147428385340250122e-04+1.147428385340250122e-06
2.00000000   4.147428385340250122e-03+9.147428385340250122e-05
3.00000000   8.147428385340250122e-04+3.147428385340250122e-04
4.00000000   8.147428385340250122e-04
```

and output should be

```
1.00000000    0.00021589026691936527
2.00000000    0.004238902669193653
3.00000000    0.00112948567706805
4.00000000    0.000814742838534025
```

I tried to write a code for the same but as i m new to `awk` programming, i am unable to findout the answer,

```
awk '{for(i=4;i<=NF;i++) t+=$i; print t; t=0}' input
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for(i=4;i<=NF;i++) t+=$i` says to sum all the numbers on a single line.

It appears that you what you really want is to sum the value in 4th column based on the value in the 1st column.

This is going to require the use of an array to hold the sums.

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
NF==4 { sums[$1]+=$4 }
END   { for (i in sums)
            printf "%s %.20f\n", i, sums[i]
      }
' input
```

This generates:

```
1.00000000 0.00021589026691936527
4.00000000 0.00081474283853402501
3.00000000 0.00112948567706805001
2.00000000 0.00423890266919365287
```

**NOTE:** expected output shows the sums with a variable number of digits to the right of the decimal; OP hasn't provided any details on how to determine which sums should have what scale so I've opted to use the same scale for all sums

The expected output shows the results sorted by the 1st column; a couple ways to do this:

**pipe output to `sort`:**

```
awk '
NF==4 { sums[$1]+=$4 }
END   { for (i in sums)
            printf "%s %.20f\n", i, sums[i]
      }
' input | sort -k1,1n
```

**using `GNU awk`:**

```
awk '
NF==4 { sums[$1]+=$4 }
END   { PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"    # sort array in ascending order by numeric index
        for (i in sums)
            printf "%s %.20f\n", i, sums[i]
      }
' input
```

Both of these sort the data by the 1st column:

```
1.00000000 0.00021589026691936527
2.00000000 0.00423890266919365287
3.00000000 0.00112948567706805001
4.00000000 0.00081474283853402501
```

Comment: ok if i have minus values on the first column it does it work ???, its giving unsorted values

Comment: which of the `awk` scripts is not sorting properly? 1st? 2nd (piped to sort) ? 3rd (using `GNU awk/PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` ?  also consider updating the question with a more realistic set of data

Comment: i think i have to add -n after sort  in second script

Comment: yes, you can add qualifiers, eg, `sort -k1,1n` or `sort -n`; updated the answer with a sample option

Comment: Thanks @markp-fuso for your clever answer, however i need at least 15 reputations to caste my vote,Howver i have accepted it.Thanks alot!!!!!!

Comment: not a problem; thanks